# Two quicksort implementations, differing comparisons

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

**UPDATE:**

I've been trying to calculate the number of comparisons made in a quicksort implementation (code below), but I noticed that the number of comparisons is only correctly computed when I take out the bold bit in the line below.

left_comparisons, left_list = quick_sort(unsorted_list **[:i - 1]**, l, i - 2)

I have two questions to ask:

1. Why should the bold bit affect the total comparisons made?
2. Why does input_list[l:r + 1] sometimes have a length of 0? Shouldn't this algorithm ensure that the base case always has 1 element in it?

$

```
def quick_sort(unsorted_list, l, r):
    if len(unsorted_list[l:r + 1]) <= 1:
        return 0, unsorted_list
    else:
        # choose_pivot(input_list)   # TODO implement properly later. cd return input_list here.
        pivot = unsorted_list[l]

        i = l + 1
        num_comparisons = r - l

        for j in xrange(l + 1, r + 1):
            if unsorted_list[j] < pivot:
                temp = unsorted_list[i]
                unsorted_list[i] = unsorted_list[j]
                unsorted_list[j] = temp
                i += 1

        unsorted_list[l] = unsorted_list[i - 1]
        unsorted_list[i - 1] = pivot

        left_comparisons, left_list = quick_sort(unsorted_list[:i - 1], l, i - 2)
        right_comparisons, right_list = quick_sort(unsorted_list, i, len(unsorted_list) - 1)

        return left_comparisons + num_comparisons + right_comparisons, left_list[:i - 1] + [pivot] + right_list[i:]
```

Comment: Why would the number of comparisons ever be an input parameter? BTW, if you abstracted the comparison to a separate function, you could track the actual number of calls without compromising the brevity of your code.

Comment: Good point. num_comparisons has been removed from the function arguments.